# Stock_Market prediction using Linear regression

Tags: python, stock

I'm trying to improve a stock_market prediction model using `LinearRegression()` on sklearn. First of all, I'm new to machine learning and I am kind of struggling on how the code works here it is:

```
df = df[["Adj Close"]] #price of closing
df["prediction"]=df[["Adj Close"]].shift(-int(30)) #creating just for 30 days
X=df.drop(["prediction"],1)
X=preprocessing.scale(X)
X_forecast=X[-int(30):]
X=X[:-int(30)]
y=np.array(df["prediction"])
y=y[:-int(30)]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2) #on fait un test en limitant les données connues et celles inconnues pour eviter l'overfitting
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
forecast_prediction=reg.predict(X_forecast)
print(forecast_prediction)
```

I don't understand how is it possible to predict something with this kind of linear regression because we are only using one data here:

```
np.array(df["prediction"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question, I must advise that a Linear Regression, especially *this specific* Linear Regression, is a very simplistic modeling method for stock prices that may not have a huge upside in terms of accuracy.

This specific [script](https://www.kaggle.com/dkmostafa/predicting-stock-market-using-linear-regression/code) from Kaggle is trying to find a correlation between a stock price and its price exactly 30 days prior.  In the example on Kaggle, we can notice that their X variable is pulled straight from `df[['Adj Close']]` while their Y variable is a shifted form of that column that they called `label` (which is your `df[['prediction']]`)

When you set X equal to `df.drop(["prediction"],1)` in line 3, you are setting X equal to the entirety of all the other columns in the data frame (this is wrong).

tl;dr: The example regression script on Kaggle works, but the underlying financial theory is unsound.  Your code has some key differences from the example script that may cause (un)foreseen errors.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
But I still don't understand your statement, I deleted the 30 last entries on purpose to have a real forecast, because what I seem to have understand in the Kaggle code is that X is actually the real prices that I want to forecast. 
So I don't quite get why if I should train my model (LinearRegression here) on data that I want to get ( future stock prices).

Comment: I think X_lately is the forecast set.  The model in the code from Kaggle is just trying to find a linear relationship between a current stock price and its price exactly some _x_ days prior.  In the code on Kaggle, _x_ is 5 and in your code _x_ is 30.  Once this relationship is established, it attempts to use it to forecast future prices.  For example, to find the price 5 days into the future, it would only look at the price 25 days in the past (if _x_ = 30).  As you can see, this is a very thin relationship probably with little correlation.